# Serving PHP image resource as response in Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, httpresponse

I am developing a web application. In my application, I need to work with some images and display it on the browser. But I am not saving the image as a file and access the file from the path. I am not doing it for some reason. Instead, I am creating an image resource from some kind of byte data and then serving it.

This is my code in the controller.

```
function serveS3Image(Request $request)
{
    $image_data = Storage::disk('s3')->get($request->get('identifier'));
    $data = imagecreatefromstring($image_data);
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($data);
}
```

When I access the action from the browser, it is displaying me correct image. But I want to do it in more Laravel way. Something like this:

```
function serveS3Image()
{
     return Response::ImageResource($data);
}
```

How can I return the PHP image resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have got the solution based on some answers. I just needed to return like this.

```
return response(Storage::disk('s3')->get($request->get('identifier')))->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
```

In the response, I passed image data, not the file path. Then I set the content type in the header. Thanks eveyone.

Answer (score 2):

I found same question on Laracast like your.
Look at [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/download-a-file-from-s3). I hope it will help to you.

**EDIT:** add code from laracast

```
public function downloadAsset($id)
{
    $asset = Asset::find($id);
    $assetPath = Storage::disk('s3')->url($asset->filename);

    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($assetPath));
    header("Content-Type: " . $asset->mime);

    return readfile($assetPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, it wasn't me who downvoted (some guys are not that patient and link-only answers tend to get downvotes..)

Comment: Sometimes I do not see the point of copying an answer from another site if it can be viewed there with other answers.

Comment: Well, the main point is accessability. Starting from one doesn't go to a third-party site to get the answer (especially in difficult cases when they're searching for an answer and some answers are not relevant) and ending with cases when a link gets broken and the answer becomes a "here's a nice solution: [broken link]" thing (quite discouraging, right?)

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-responses

The file method may be used to display a file, such as an image or PDF, directly in the user's browser instead of initiating a download.

This method accepts the path to the file as its first argument and an array of headers as its second argument:

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);

return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);
```

Comment: I am not saving the image as a file. I am getting that image data from some kind of api.

Comment: have you tried?   $img = Image::make($contentOfTheImage ));
    return $img->response('png', 70);